# Pronunciation of "null"

Tags: pronunciation

I used to watch some tutorials and the instructor was **native American**. There was a term in the program that was called "**null object**". And he used to pronounce "null" like /**nʊl**/. Recently I faced "null" in Longman Dictionary and I saw it's pronounced like /**nʌl**/. I'm pretty sure that I had heard it correctly. Because this object was used a lot in the program and the instructor used to call its name every time he wanted to use it. And I think this is why I got shocked when I saw the new pronunciation in Longman. Is that correct to pronounce it like he used to pronounce despite this fact that the pronunciation in Longman Dictionary is different?

Comment: There is a wide regional variation of the way both vowels and consonants are pronounced. For example in UK the words 'luck' and 'look' are pronounced one way in some areas, or the opposite way round, or the same as each other.

Comment: Are these tutorials online?

Comment: @JamesK Yes, but they're not live. You could either watch them online or download the video files to watch them even when you're offline.

Comment: What I mean is, please provide the link to the tutorials. It may be a regional dialect, or you may hear something that native speakers don't, or it may just be a speech defect by this one person. If you can provide the link you may get better answers.  By the way take care with "native American".  To many people that means the same as "American Indian", ie from the native peoples of America.

Comment: @JamesK Yes, you're absolutely right. Here is the link: https://youtu.be/kP55KVBkGJo?t=202 at 3':22". And for the second point you mentioned, What would I have to say to determine that I'm talking about a person that their mother tongue is English and is from the US?

Comment: @JamesK Here is another link: https://youtu.be/5ekOxpMIVYg?t=1428 at 23':50". He says "null object" again so you can make sure that he pronounces like this in every situation.

Comment: You could say "A native speaker of American English".  And you are right, this is indeed a native speaker of English in the video.

Comment: @JamesK Hello again. I've been watching some other tutorials and I found a new guy who pronounces the word "null" exactly like the way that the previous guy used to pronounce. I'm wondering if you could check this link out to see if it is following the California vowel shift rule? Here is the link: https://youtu.be/SAlvDJcrBRU?t=43 at 0':43"

Comment: Yes, sounds like /nɜl/  which would suggest the Californian Vowel shift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/I don't hear /nʊl/  I hear something like /nɜl/ even approaching /nɛl/

This is the "[California vowel shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_English#California_vowel_shift), a chain of vowel movements that is occurring among native speakers of English on the West coast of America.

Answer (score 0):

Best is to follow the below pronunciation:

> /nuhl/

Below is the UK transcription for "null":

1. Modern IPA: /**nə́l**/
2. Traditional IPA: /**nʌl**/
3. 1 syllable: /**"NUL"**/

In [Faroese](https://www.faroeislands.fo/arts-culture/language/), it is pronounced as /**nʊl**/.

Either way, both should be fine.

More information on "null" on [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/null)